# WinApi SendMessage/PostMessage doesn't work on my Computer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I wrote some test code in c# (using WPF Form) to check if sendMessage/PostMessage will work.
Here is:

```
        Process x = Process.GetProcessesByName("Any Apps")[0];
        if (x == null) return;
        MessageBox.Show(x.Id.ToString()); // always works
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(x.MainWindowHandle, 0x100, 0x70, 0);//F1
        NativeMethods.SendMessage(x.MainWindowHandle, 0x101, 0x70, 0);
```

Finding process work anywhere, but sendingMessage/postingMessage have never worked when I run the app with via VS debug key. Sometimes it works when I start the program from desktop, sometimes not. But... what's intresting: On any avaiable machines (VM with XP, Another computer with 64bit Windows 7, friends computer with 32bit Windows 7) works fast and fine.

Have anyone the same problem? Maby someone know the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Of course* it works, otherwise you wouldn't get a GUI desktop, just a DOS prompt. What are you expecting sending messages 0x100 and 0x101 to *do* exactly?

Comment: I'm excepting that it will work like on other machines. I don't have any idea why it is working everywhere except of my notebook (which I'm using to programming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SendMessage` and `PostMessage` work fine - but sending key strokes in Windows is not as simple as you imagine.  Just sending `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages isn't a reliable to send input.  The messages are being sent, but the window you are sending them to is ignoring them.

1. The keyboard state is not managed correctly: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx)
2. Windows applications have many different windows, the main window may not be the handles keyboard input.  In Windows keystorkes go to the focused window - which may not be the main window - think of the main MS Word window and the sub document windows for example.
3. Commands like `F1` are usually implemented as [keyboard accelerators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that send `WM_COMMAND` messages - I do not beileve that fake `WM_KEYDOWN` & `WM_KEYUP` messages will trigger them.

Comment: The probably reason of not working is blocking F1 event by another app. I'll test it and uncheck the answer as correct if i'm wrong.

Comment: Correct. And this application is TeamViewer 8. Watch out for that.

Answer (score 2):

Right, this code will not in general work.  It starts with WM_KEYDOWN/UP being posted, not sent.  But more serious is that MainWindowHandle property is not in general the handle of a window that was designed to receive keyboard input.  It is often a *frame window*, displaying things like a menu and toolbar.  A window that receives input is normally a *child window* of the frame window.  Like a TextBox control.  Notepad is an example of an application that's structured this way.

Use the Spy++ tool to get insight in the window hierarchy of a particular application.

Otherwise, the only hope of making this code ever generic is to bring the main window to the foreground (pinvoke SetForegroundWindow) and to simulate keyboard strokes (pinvoke SendInput).